# ctrl+left click not editing terrain Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-development-kit

When I press ctrl + left click in UDK it's doing nothing to the terrain. I've tried both ctrl keys & still can't seem to find the issue.

A picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your picture you seem to have the wrong tool selected. Smooth does not take Ctrl + clicks, only Add/Remove Sectors, Vertex Paint, Paint, Visibility, etc. See [the user guide](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/TerrainEditorUserGuide.html) for more info.

Also as a side note, there isn't anything wrong with StackOverflow, but the Epic Games Forums is much more responsive when it comes to UDK issues :)